# Reykeyed AES in CTR mode as a stream cipher

Tags: block-cipher, stream-cipher, modes-of-operation

Suppose one uses AES in CTR mode to generate a keystream, but every $l$ bytes the $n$ bits that would follow are used as a new AES key.

Assuming that AES is a secure PRP:

- Is this a secure stream cipher?
- How does it compare to standard AES-CTR?
- Suppose the (original) key is mixed back in at each rekeying useing a one-way pseudorandom compression: what changes?

Note that AES is used as an example secure block cipher.

Comment: I think this will eventually fall into a cycle after about $2^{k/2}$ new keys, where $k$ is the length of the key in bits.

Comment: Until then, is it harder (vs. AES) to distinguish from a PRP?